# Cocoa touch framework to embed some native libraries

Tags: c++, ios, frameworks, embed

I'm developing a framework that's using a third party library which is  Boost native, I compiled my framework and called methods from Boost and everything is perfect.

but when I included the framework into another application, the application complaining about the Boost library so I have to add the Boost library to the application

can't I embed the library into my framework, so I can use only the framework in my application without caring about the Boost library??

Thanks Much
/George

Comment: Maybe you should compile Boost as a static library inside your framework

Comment: I compiled it  and set the headers search path to the include folder and linked against the boost.a library file for the framework, but you have to do the same also when you include the framwork in an application